# Making exceptions in Arraydeque don't stop the execution

Tags: c++, exception, arraydeque

I'm building a Deque and I just when to send a message to the user when an exception occurs. So, I'm using an exception in a try to delete from an empty list:

ArrayDequeClass:

```
 void ArrayDeque::deleteFront(){
  //Just check if list it's empty. If it is, it throw the exception.
  if(isEmpty())throw new logic_error("You can't delete from an empty 
  list");
  data.erase(data.begin()+front);

}
```

Calling the function on the main:

```
try{
  deque->deleteFront();
}catch(logic_error e){
   cout<<e.what();
}
```

The output is: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error*'

When I try to delete from my empty array. I included stdexcept.

How I can just return the message: "You can't delete from an empty 
  list"

Comment: Just a piece of general advice; don't catch exceptions by value. Always catch them by const reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing a pointer with `throw new`. That doesn't match the catch clause expecting an object by value.

Just remove the `new`. (And optionally catch by const-reference).